# MVC4 Razor Multiple strongly type partial view with action in one page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, partial-views

I have a requirement where I have Login and Register form in Homepage. I believe this quite a common scenario however I am having difficulty achieving this.

This Login and Register forms are two separate Strongly Type Partial View which is being used in Index view

Below is the controller for Register. I will skip the login since if I get this to work, the other should be similar.

**Register Controller**

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/Register

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel registerModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                _webSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(registerModel.Email, registerModel.Password,
                                                 new { registerModel.FirstName, registerModel.LastName, registerModel.Email });
                _webSecurity.Login(registerModel.Email, registerModel.Password);

                return RedirectToAction("Manage", "Account");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(registerModel);
    }
```

**Index Controller**

```
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //
        // If logedin redirect to profile page
        // Else show home page view
        //

        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Manage", "Account", new { id = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name });
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Register View**

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@model BoilKu.Web.ViewModels.RegisterModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register","Account", FormMethod.Post)) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </li>
           ...
           ... Omitted codes
           ...
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Index View**

```
@model BoilKu.Web.ViewModels.HomeModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@{
    Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account");
}
@{
    Html.RenderAction("Register", "Account");
}
```

Now with the above code, I have managed to get the partial view to display on the homepage. However when I click "Register" after filling up the details it will automatically redirect to my Register page with the fields pre populated. This is not what I want. I expect the register to happened on the homepage and redirect to Profile page when it has successfully registered. How do I go about doing this? Thank you for reading and apology for the noobishe questions. I am still quite new to MVC.

**Update**
Changing the Register Controller return from PartialView() to View() will act according the above requirement. However it will embed the page into a page. (i.e. the top navigation will be duplicated. )
Anyone?

Comment: See my answer Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924813/asp-net-mvc-4-html-beginform-in-partial-view-values-after-post-not-right/19928480#19928480

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create a partial page (user control) for register view

_register.cshtml

(no change here, just removed the script section. Parent view will render necessary script)

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@model BoilKu.Web.ViewModels.RegisterModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register","Account", FormMethod.Post)) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
        </li>
           ...
           ... Omitted codes
           ...
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</fieldset>
}
```

index.cshtml

inside the HomeModel, it needs to have a RegisterModel property

```
@model BoilKu.Web.ViewModels.HomeModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@{
    Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account");
}
@{
    @Html.Partial("register", Model.RegisterModel)
}
```

When I create a MVC application, i usually retrieve all the information that is required by the page and put it into the model. In this scenario, HomeModel contains RegisterModel details.  Then inside the view, you can render partial page and just pass the model as an argument. Partial view doesn't have to go back to the controller.

Then in your Register page, you can partial render

```
@Html.Partial("register", Model.RegisterModel)
```

Comment: Hi Raver, Thanks for responding. Unfortunately it is still not working as expected. It is still redirecting to the Register Page. I wonder if this can only be achieved using AJAX. I would have thought this would not need be the case. I suspect the issue might lies with the return type in the controller. Do you have any insight on this? Thanks

Comment: i think its not redirecting to the Account page becauase its not reaching this line of code "return RedirectToAction("Manage", "Account");" i think there's some exception happen during the login process. If you put some break point during the Register postback, what happens? where does it take you?